Interaction system with asynchronous interactions
A common approach to creating an interaction system is to use an IInteractable interface. The Player checks for collisions with an IInteractable, then calls Interact on it when a button is pressed. The IInteractable interface is implemented by anything that can be interacted with, e.g. a door, a chest, a sign, etc. The below code showcases the basic premise.
My question is, how are asynchronous interactions typically handled in this type of system?
Right now, it is assumed that every interaction happens in an instant / takes no time. But what if the door takes, say, 3 second to open, and we want to stop the player from being able to move, or interact again, during that time period? What would be a good way to add that feature?
public interface IInteractable
{
    void Interact(GameObject otherInteractor);
}

public class DoorInteractable : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public void Interact(GameObject otherInteractor)
    {
        OpenDoor();
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IInteractable currentInteractable;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactableDetected))
        {
            currentInteractable = interactableDetected;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactableDetected))
        {
            currentInteractable = null;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && currentInteractable != null)
        {
            currentInteractable.Interact(gameObject);
        }
    }
}


I have done more research, and came across Awaitable. It is similar to C#'s Task, but is specifically tailored for Unity.
Using that, I have changed my code as follows to achieve my goal.
public interface IInteractable
{
    Awaitable InteractAsync(GameObject otherInteractor);
}

public class DoorInteractable : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public async Awaitable InteractAsync(GameObject otherInteractor)
    {
        OpenDoor();

        await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(3);
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerMover playerMover;

    private bool isInteracting = false;

    private IInteractable currentInteractable;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactableDetected))
        {
            currentInteractable = interactableDetected;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable interactableDetected))
        {
            currentInteractable = null;
        }
    }

    async void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && currentInteractable != null && !isInteracting)
        {
            isInteracting = true;            
            playerMover.DisableMovement();

            await currentInteractable.Interact(gameObject);

            isInteracting = false;
            playerMover.EnableMovement();
        }
    }
}


My experience is that in any sufficiently advanced game, the PlayerController will either become a finite state machine, or a horrible abomination of spaghetti code with half a dozen flags (isRunning, isJumping, isLookingAtInventory,isTouchingDoorHandle etc.) that really should be refactored into a finite state machine.
So if you want an interaction to put the player into a state where they can't move or interact, then it would make sense to represent this as a separate state in the player FSM.
Which means that an IInteractible would cause a transition to the "Interacting" state on beginning the interaction, and then back to the default state when ending the interaction. In order to avoid bugs, you should probably also make sure that the interactible object puts the player back into its default state when it is disabled or destroy during the interaction.

I might have the Interact method return an InteractionToken, or null if the interaction has completed instantly.
This could look something like this:
public class InteractionToken {
    bool _completed;
    public bool IsComplete => _completed;

    public event System.Action OnComplete;

    public void MarkCompleted() {
        Assert.IsFalse(_completed, "Double-completing an interaction is not allowed");
        _completed = true;
        OnComplete?.Invoke();
    }
}

Now your player class can check if the return value is non-null, and if so, put its input/control logic into a "paused" state while it waits for the interaction to complete.
You can either poll IsComplete each frame to see if it's time to resume normal play, or subscribe to the OnComplete event to be notified when to resume.
This token would also be a good place to log a cancellation request, if you want some actions to be cancellable, or to track percent progress / time remaining if you want to show a progress bar or use it to vary an animation, sound, or visual effect, things like that.
